# Conditional probability of picking balls

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

Suppose that a bag contains $11$ black balls and $9$ white balls. A child takes out a ball $6$ consecutive times, each time replacing the one taken (with a ball of the same color). Find the probability of that he takes out $5$ black balls given that exactly $2$ of the first $3$ times he takes out balls, they were black?

I have absolutely no idea how to approach this problem. It mentions that replacement is involved which implies that binomial distribution may be used. Any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: Exactly two of the first three times he took out balls they were black and exactly one of the first three times it was white.  It doesn't actually matter which of the three was white... we don't care.  Now...  the only unknown for us is the following three balls, all of which must be black for the overall total to have been 5 black out of the six.  So, reword the question... "*A child takes out a ball* **3** *times, each time replacing the one taken.  Find the probability that he takes out* **3 black balls**"

Comment: @JMoravitz I see. What if it asked about $4$ balls instead of $5$? Would that make the probability $(\frac{9 \cdot 11 \cdot 11}{20})^3$?

Comment: No.  You mentioned the binomial distribution in your post, you should have paid closer attention to it.  That would have been the probability of getting a white *then* a black *then* a black if they were drawn in sequence.  We don't care though if the white was the fourth, fifth, or sixth ball so you are off by a factor of $3$, or if you prefer so it fits with the usual formula as written, off by a factor of $\binom{3}{2}$

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

1. The verbiage about replacement simply means that just before each draw of a golf ball, there are exactly 11 black and 9 white balls.
2. The given condition that 2 of the 1st 3 draws are black **reduces** the problem to asking what are the chances that the next three draws are **all** black.  In other words, the original problem + the assumed event equate to the alternative problem of : what are the chances that the **first** 3 draws are all black.

Comment: So basically, what is the probability of taking out $3$ black balls from the $3$ (remaining) draws? Wouldn't that be $(\frac{11}{20})^3$?

Comment: @Kraftsman yes exactly.

Comment: Nevermind my other question. Thank you!